# How call functions from data base in EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I generate a model from my database.

In the .edmx file I have a row string

```
<Function Name="GetUniqueInt" ReturnType="int" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" />
```

as its cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create [stub method for your function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847.aspx) somewhere. It should look like:

```
[EdmFunction("YourModelNamespace", "GetUniqueInt")]
public static int GetUniqueInt()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

Place this method for example to your context class and use it in LINQ queries.

Comment: I not understand "throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");" not have to change?

Comment: It is stub method. It is supposed to be called only in Linq-to-entities query where its content is never called because it is translated to your SQL function call.