# extend linq to entities to recognize custom methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867100/workarounds-for-using-custom-methods-extension-methods-in-linq-to-entities) and in countless more: I'd like to know if there is ANY way to inherit/extend/... Entity Framework 4.1 to translate a custom method to SQL.

Comment: I protest the downvote.
I did plenty of research and people all over are focusing on avoiding the question I am posing. Hardly anyone is talking about providing EF with the SQL equivalent of a method to enable them to be mingled with Linq to Entities. It deserves to be posed as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you if you are using EDMX, you can either use [model defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612827/entity-framework-where-do-i-extend-the-csdl-msl/5613642#5613642) or [custom SQL / mapped SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383747/how-call-functions-from-data-base-in-ef) exposed as .NET method available in Linq-to-Entities query.

None of these techniques is available with code-first.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer based on your experience, can you authenticate this in some way with documentation or blogs from MS? I didn't find any...

Comment: I found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/39b8d6cd-5c77-40e4-abf3-d620c79b8ff2/ a question posed by you. I guess that's my answer then :)